# Adding New Column in an Existing CSV File using CsvHelper

Tags: vb.net, csv, csvhelper

I wanna add one new header in my existing file.

What I have tried is this:

```
Public Class ImportData
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub Start(fo As FileInfo)
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fo.FullName)
            Using csv As CsvWriter = New CsvWriter(sw)
                csv.WriteHeader(Of Modules)()
                csv.NextRecord()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Class Modules
        Public Name As String

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public NotInheritable Class ModulesMap
        Inherits ClassMap(Of Modules)

        Public Sub New()
            Map(Function(m) m.Name).Name("app_module.name")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

After executing, the data is gone after opening it.